# Hidden Field Value in dd/MM/yyyy format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the `hidden` field in my `View` which is in List `foreach` Loop.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].List[q].EntryDate)
```

I want the `format` of this hidden field to be `dd/MM/yyyy`. Currently when the data is binded this date also includes time.

I have used a global `UTCDateTimeModelBinder` which parses datetime model value like this :-

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(value.AttemptedValue.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

So it gives me error if the time is present in the datetime model value.

Comment: What is the value of `value.AttemptedValue.Trim()` exactly?

Comment: It is Date Value like `31/12/2015`. If time is present in Date like `31/12/2015 00:00:00` It obviously gives error.

Comment: Could you expose a string property that formats the `DateTime` to that format and use that instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are more than one possible formats for your inputs, you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact(String, String[], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes your formats as a string array.

```
string[] formats = new string[]{"dd/MM/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"};
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(value.AttemptedValue.Trim(), formats, 
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: Sometimes The Value also comes like '01/01/2015 12:00:00 AM' & it crashes.

Comment: @Anup Then you need _also_ add `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` format to your `formats` array.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving an error because the format you have specified does not match the input string. If you are not concerned with the time part of the string then simply:

```
    var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(value.AttemptedValue.Trim().Substring(0,10), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```